# sorting entity in coredata to textView?

Tags: ios, core-data

i am at a loss, i'm using core data to record guests at an event; all is working fine with Guest for entity, and 3 attributes, LastName, Name and ZipCode. In order to show the user his guests i am displaying the guests in a non editable textView, all i want is to display the guests in an alphabetical order in that textview since now they are now listed by order of time they were entered into the app. Here is the code that is pausing the problem :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

[self drawText];
[super viewDidLoad];

AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Guest" inManagedObjectContext:appDelegate.managedObjectContext];
[request setEntity:entity];

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
NSError *error;
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
NSString*guestString =@"";

for(NSManagedObject *obj in fetchedObjects) {

    guestString =[guestString stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@\n",[obj valueForKey:@"guestLastName" ],[obj valueForKey:@"guestName"],[obj valueForKey:@"guestZipCode"];
}

self.textView.text = guestString;
for(NSManagedObject *obj in fetchedObjects)
{
    NSLog(@"Name:%@\n Last Name %@\n" , [obj valueForKey:@"guestName"],[obj valueForKey:@"guestLastName"]);
   }  
}
```

Any Help greatly appreciated since i am trying to sorts thing out but to no avail ? Thanking in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this..

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

[self drawText];
[super viewDidLoad];

AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Guest" inManagedObjectContext:appDelegate.managedObjectContext];
[request setEntity:entity];

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
NSError *error;
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [[[context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error]sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"guestName" ascending:YES]]mutableCopy];
 NSString*guestString =@"";

for(NSManagedObject *obj in fetchedObjects) {

 guestString =[guestString stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@\n",[obj valueForKey:@"guestLastName" ],[obj valueForKey:@"guestName"],[obj valueForKey:@"guestZipCode"];
}

self.textView.text = guestString;
for(NSManagedObject *obj in fetchedObjects)
{
NSLog(@"Name:%@\n Last Name %@\n" , [obj valueForKey:@"guestName"],[obj valueForKey:@"guestLastName"]);
}  
}
```

Comment: thank you so much Jincy Sam that got it working....i must admit i was really faffing around with those sortDescriptors and was getting very muddled up....thanks again

Answer (score 0):

i hope below code will help you to solve your problem

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"guestName" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
NSArray *sortDescs = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
[request setSortDescriptors:sortDescs];
```

Comment: Thanks Pritesh but alas no...it's still just displaying entries in the order they were entered.

Comment: try this @selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)

Comment: thank you Pritesh for your answers i used the Jincy Sam's answer and it is now displaying the entities in alphabetical order.Thanks.